# Limit number of concurrent thread in a thread pool

Tags: multithreading, threadpool

In my code I have a loop, inside this loop I send several requests to a remote webservice. WS providers said: "The webservice can host at most *n* threads", so i need to cap my code since I can't send *n+1* threads.

If I've to send *m* threads I would that first *n* threads will be executed immediately and as soon one of these is completed a new thread (one of the remaining *m-n* threads) will be executed and so on, until all *m* threads are executed.

I have thinked of a [Thread Pool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx) and [explicit setting of the max thread number to *n*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1). Is this enough?

Comment: Why not wrap the entire for loop so that a single background threadpool thread does the entire loop. This way you do not have to worry about the thread creation etc.

Comment: Are you really the only user of that web service?  Unusual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this I would avoid the use of multiple threads. Instead, wrapping the entire loop up which can be run on a single thread. However, if you do want to launch multiple threads using the/a thread pool then I would use the `Semaphore` class to facilitate the required thread limit; here's how...

A semaphore is like a mean night club bouncer, it has been provide a club capacity and is not allowed to exceed this limit. Once the club is full, no one else can enter... A queue builds up outside. Then as one person leaves another can enter (analogy thanks to J. Albahari).

A `Semaphore` with a value of one is equivalent to a `Mutex` or `Lock` except that the `Semaphore` has no owner so that it is thread ignorant. Any thread can call `Release` on a `Semaphore` whereas with a `Mutex`/`Lock` only the thread that obtained the `Mutex`/`Lock` can release it.

Now, for your case we are able to use `Semaphore`s to limit concurrency and prevent too many threads from executing a particular piece of code at once. In the following example five threads try to enter a night club that only allows entry to three...

```
class BadAssClub
{
    static SemaphoreSlim sem = new SemaphoreSlim(3);
    static void Main()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) 
            new Thread(Enter).Start(i);
    }

    // Enfore only three threads running this method at once.
    static void Enter(int i)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i + " wants to enter.");
            sem.Wait();
            Console.WriteLine(i + " is in!");
            Thread.Sleep(1000 * (int)i);
            Console.WriteLine(i + " is leaving...");
        }
        finally
        {
            sem.Release();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

---

*Edit. You can also use the [`ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads.aspx) Method. This method restricts the number of threads allowed to run in the thread pool. But it does this 'globally' for the thread pool itself. This means that if you are running SQL queries or other methods in libraries that you application uses then new threads will not be spun-up due to this blocking. This may not be relevant to you, in which case use the `SetMaxThreads` method. If you want to block for a particular method however, it is safer to use `Semphores`.*

Comment: Yeah, this helps! Can you explain me what's the use of ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads method? Thank you :)

Comment: PS: One single thread will be not so usefull. Cause the WS response spend a lot of time, luckly the WS is optimized for multiple instances, so multiple threads will do the job!

Comment: Sets the number of requests to the thread pool that can be active concurrently. All requests above that number remain queued until thread pool threads become available. Use caution when changing the maximum number of threads in the thread pool. While your code might benefit, the changes might have an adverse effect on code libraries you use.

Setting the thread pool size too large can cause performance problems. If too many threads are executing at the same time, the task switching overhead becomes a significant factor.

Comment: I've read that doc, I was just wondering if the words "the number of requests to the thread pool that can be active concurrently" means the same things that I mean, and, if that's true: use this approach directly avoiding the semaphore.

Comment: Yes, this method restricts the number of threads allowed to run in the thread pool. But as the second part of the comment above states, it does this 'globally' for the thread pool itself. This means that if you are running SQL queries or other methods in libraries that you application uses then new threads will not be spun-up due to this blocking. This may not be relevant to you, in which case use the `SetMaxThreads` method. If you want to block for a particular method however, it is safer to use `Semphores`... Cheers.

Comment: Ok, perfect. 
You could merge this comment with original answer, it was really userfull.

Comment: Good answer. It's worth putting the `release` in a finally block, otherwise the semaphore will be depleted by exceptions.